# Is this an optimal chain in terms of memory management?

Tags: c#, caching, properties, memorycache

We have a system that loads C# poco objects into memory. (Deserialized from data source on disk). They are further cached in ObjectCache (MemoryCache.Default) and exposed via a Repository class. The chain goes like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, T> itemsDictionary;
    private Dictionary<string, T> ItemsDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsDictionary ?? (itemsDictionary = RepositoryLoader.Load());        
        }
    }

    private List<T> itemsList;
    private List<T> ItemsList
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsList ?? (itemsList = ItemsDictionary.Values.ToList());
        }
    }

    public List<T> All { get { return ItemsList; } }
```

**RepositoryLoader.Load() - This caches the items in a memory cache as Dictionary**...

My question is - as you can see it also goes via 2 cached properties - does it create a duplication on memory consumption or not ? :) Is there a way to optimize this chain ?

Comment: The `Values` property is already an `ICollection<T>`. You could expose that as a property. Is there a reason you want it as a `List<T>`? If so, what? Maybe there's a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `T` is a `class`, having both the `itemsDictionary` and `itemsList` means that you have two references to the same memory locations. Assuming the items are each large, e.g. complex objects, this is negligible (4 or 8 bytes per item, depending on if you're running 32- or 64-bit). If the items are `struct`s, however, this means they will be duplicated, and you'll be using double the memory.

If the memory usage is an issue and you'll only need the `ItemsList` at certain times, you might want to drop the `itemsList` field and just make the property generate it on the fly:

```
return ItemsDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

Another option, assuming you have control over the `RepositoryLoader` functionality, is to write an [`IDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) implementation that exposes its `Values` as, e.g. an [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) directly, without recreating the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! yes, T is a class (not struct). Could you please direct me to some example on IReadonlyList<T> for my context?